# ScrollRestoration not work in mobile devices for React js project

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my react project I use React Router for routing path. My main layout is conditional. To prevent scroll I use React Router `ScrollRestoration`. All is OK for laptop devices but for mobile devices it is not working at all.

```
<div>
            {/* login - homepage if user not exist */}
            {userId == null && (
                <div className="min-h-screen">
                    <div className="logTop1">
                        <div className="flex justify-center items-center py-2 px-4 w-full">
                            <Link to="/" className="block">
                                <img
                                    src="/images/icons/"
                                    width={130}
                                    height={50}
                                    alt="nav cover image"
                                />
                            </Link>

                            <Link
                                to="/login"
                                style={{ borderRadius: "30px" }}
                                className="w-[100px] font-medium hidden lg:block bg-[#343a40] text-white text-center p-4 ml-auto rounded-[30px] text-[14px] leading-5"
                            >
                                Login
                            </Link>
                            <Link
                                to="/register"
                                style={{ borderRadius: "30px" }}
                                className="w-[100px] font-medium hidden lg:block bg-[#1E74FD] text-white text-center p-4 rounded-[30px] text-[14px] leading-5 ml-2"
                            >
                                Register
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="logHome1">
                        <div className="logHome2"></div>
                        <div className="logHome3">
                            <div className="logHome4 mx-auto">
                                <Outlet />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}

            {/* if user is exist then load main page  */}
            {userId && <UsersLayout></UsersLayout>}
            <ScrollRestoration />
        </div>
```

I tried in both large and small devices. I want scroll restoration to work for both devices.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.